# Symbolic Link command behavior ln -s

Tags: linux, command-line, symlink

If I issue `ln -s source.txt symlink.txt` and `symlink.txt` does not already exist, is a link file automatically created called `symlink.txt` or is the command a noop?

If it is a noop, if I just create a blank `symlink.txt` (`touch symlink.txt`) and then run the previous command will the operation works as planned?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tested these 2 commands you say? What did you get?

Comment: You don't need to create the target symlink.

Comment: And always use the full paths both the source and the symlink.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, using a full (absolute) path for the symlink target would make it a different symlink. It depends on what you want to happen if you move/copy the link or the whole directory tree, of course

Comment: are you asking "if it try to create the file `symlink.txt` and it dose not exist, then does nothing happen? Did you get this the right way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's easy to test:

```
$ mkdir test; cd test
test$ ln -s source.txt symlink.txt
test$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 10 Oct 23 18:24 symlink.txt -> source.txt
test$ cat symlink.txt 
cat: symlink.txt: No such file or directory
```

(Representing that output as text doesn't do justice to GNU ls, and the coloring support it has.)

The `ln -s` commands creates the symlink `symlink.txt` regardless of if `source.txt` exists. Trying to access the file through the symlink doesn't work, though, since the pointed-to file doesn't exist. With output coloring, `ls` would show the link name and target as red (or whatever the setting is, something other than a live link, anyway.)

If `symlink.txt` exists, `ln -s source.txt symlink.txt` gives an error, predictably. Use `ln -sf` to overwrite the target file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `ln` will create the link file and if the file exists, it will fail (unless you use the `-f` or `--force` option).

Btw. running the command or reading the man page would give you the answer way faster ;-)

Comment: I order to fully answer such a deep, thought-provoking question, you may also mention that `ln -fs src dst` is inherently racy, and it may actually fail despite the `-f`, and you may end up with `dst` pointing somewhere else.